# UIView Bouncing like iOS Control Centre

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uidynamicanimator

I'm trying to make an UIView that can have similar behaviour like iOS control centre. My current code is able to do pull up to show and pull down to hide.

```
#define kViewMaxHeight 600
#define kViewMinHeight 300
#define kViewWidth [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
#define kViewDefaultX 0
#define kScreenHeight [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

- (void)swipeView:(id)sender {
CGPoint location = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender locationInView:self];
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender translationInView:self];
CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender velocityInView:self];
NSLog(@"x:%.2f, y:%.2f", location.x, location.y);
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    firstX = [self center].x;
    firstY = [self center].y;
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

// Dragged Up
if (velocity.y < 0) {
    if (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height > kScreenHeight) {
        [self setCenter:translatedPoint];
    }
    else {

    }
}
// Dragged Down
else {
    [self setCenter:translatedPoint];
}

//
if (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height < kScreenHeight) {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = kScreenHeight - kViewMinHeight;
    self.frame = frame;
}

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    if (velocity.y < 0 || location.y < 0) {
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.origin.y = kScreenHeight - kViewMinHeight;
        self.frame = frame;
    }
    else {
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.origin.y = kScreenHeight - 50;
        frame.size.height = kViewMinHeight;
        self.frame = frame;
    }
}
}
```

Demo:
[image: My Program]
[image: iOS Control Centre]

**Question 1:**
Can anyone give some example or guide how can i achieve this?

**Question 2(Some Stupid Question here):**
How iOS Control Centre is implemented? Is it using UIViewController or an UIView?

Comment: Control centre is most likely neither a UIView nor a UIViewController, it is probably just hardcoded into iOS

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UIGravityBehavior and UICollisionBehavior. When the user pulls up the panel, add it to the collision behavior, and when they pull it down turn off the collision behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the movement by using UIView animation with spring. Adjust values for duration, damping ratio, velocity and increase center.y until you find the right combo. Here should be a good start for you:

```
// sliding up
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    // Assuming self is the view
    self.center.y += 50
    }

// sliding down, subtract the value for center.y
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    // Assuming self is the view
    self.center.y -= 50
    }
```

Extra tweaks, check out the component I crated here: 
https://github.com/narumolp/NMPAnchorOverlayView